# Creating point on surface in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, ogr2ogr, centroids, point-creation

As far as I can tell, the option to "Create point on surface for each part" in the QGIS Centroid tool is not returning the correct geometry when activated in QGIS (version 3.8.1-Zanzibar/GDAL v 2.2.3 on Debian).

If we take a simple *"banana-shaped"* polygon:

[image]

and run the tool (`Vector > Geometry Tools > Centroids`) as follows:

[image]

we get the following output, which represents the centroid, but not the point on surface.

[image]

We can cross check this output using ogr2ogr as follows:

```
ogr2ogr -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT ST_Centroid(geometry) FROM tmp" tmp_centroid.shp tmp.shp
```

which returns the identical centroid:

[image]

whereas the following command forces the point on the surface of the polygon:

```
ogr2ogr -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT ST_PointOnSurface(geometry) FROM tmp" tmp_ptonsurf.shp tmp.shp
```

[image]

is this a bug or is there something else that should be run/enabled in order to get the point on surface using the QGIS tool?

Comment: There's a seperate algorithm for "point on surface". Have you tried that one?

Comment: thanks, yes, i saw the "point on surface" tool in the processing toolbox, which returns the correct point, but still wondering about the issue with the checkbox.

Comment: The description of the tool talk only about centroid and not point on surface, I think that the error is in the text next to the check box that should be "create centroid for each part" (try with a multipart polygon and see if the check box modify the output...)

Comment: thanks - agreed - this appears to have been updated in QGIS 3.10 as outlined below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In QGIS 3.10 this option is not available using `Vector > Geometry Tools > Centroids`.

[image]

However if you search for ["Point on surface"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#point-on-surface)  in the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) using QGIS 3.10 the functionality is there and works.

[image]

[image]